# Get names of control in code behind when clicked, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol and I want to get the names of the control user clicks on this usercontrol.

The Usercontrol xaml is given below:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
 <ListView Name ="ListView1">
  <listbox.resources>
   <Datatemplate>
     <Togglebutton Name="Button1">
     </Togglebutton>
   </Datatemplate>
  </listbox.resources>
 </Listview>
 <Border Name="Border1">
 <ContentControl>
 </ContentControl>
 </Border>
</Grid>
```

Now in my code behind, I wrote:

```
this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mouseclicked);

private void mouseclicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = e?.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if (source != null)
        {
            var parent = source.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            string name = string.Empty;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                name = parent.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                name = source.Name;
            }

            //If clicked outside the usercontrol, then usercontrol should close down
            if (!(name.Contains("Border1") || name.Contains("Grid1"))) //very strange values sometimes null or empty
            {
                //then do something
            }
        }
    }
```

**How can I get the names of the controls used in my Usercontrol in codebehind**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gave the grid, border and listview a name in XAML. This you should access in codebehind and check in the *mouseclicked* event, which element is mouse over.

```
private void mouseclicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.IsMouseOver && Grid1.IsMouseOver)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List view clicked");
    }

    if (Border1.IsMouseOver && Grid1.IsMouseOver)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Border1 clicked");
    }

    if (Grid1.IsMouseOver)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Grid1 clicked");
    }            
}
```

This would may be not the best, but could work to get the names of controls the user has clicked.